# How to access Child UI files

Tags: c++, qt

How can i access ui files of children of a class. Lets say MainWindow class has twoa child dialog. I want to access LINEEDIT of dialog so that i can take text from there. Similarly how can i access ui files of parent inside child class in QT. 
Note:
    I havn't inherited any thing from Parent class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the beginner tutorials of Qt.  The `ui` files just carry XML that the uic can read to turn into 'real' C++ for the compiler.  If you need to send data between decoupled UI components, use Signals/Slots - a fundamental building block in the Qt framework.